# Google Nexus 7 indicating it has no camera

Tags: android, android-camera, tablet

When my app runs on a Google Nexus 7 Tablet it returns false for this standard Android test to see if the device is equipped with a camera.

```
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    if(!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // disable camera button
    }
```

Now I realize that the Nexus 7 doesn't ship with a built in camera app, but when I do try to launch a camera activity I use the following (to give the user the option to pick alternate apps).

```
    File fTempCameraFullDirPath = new File(msTempCameraFullDirPath);
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( fTempCameraFullDirPath );
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
    cameraIntent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(cameraIntent, getString(R.string.select_camera_app)), REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
```

Now clearly I don't get to this code because the test for a camera fails and I disable the button, but it seems like as long as I have a camera app installed on my Nexus 7 table that I should be able to take pictures.

Does anyone know of an alternate test that I can use to enable this functionality on this tablet (or similar devices)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check for [`FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT), as the Nexus 7 only has a front-facing camera.

Answer (score 4):

Try checking for `PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT` as well as `FEATURE_CAMERA`, since the Nexus 7 only has the front-facing camera, and the Android camera selection algorithm defaults to the rear camera.

Answer (score 4):

As an update to the answer:

Since **API Level 17** you can also check for [`PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY) which indicates if the device has any camera whatsoever regardless of its position.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_CAMERA) it says FEATURE_CAMERA pertains to the camera facing away from the screen which is esentially the back camera. So rightfully it should return false.